# How do I prevent `git` from merging text lines if both sides have changes in the same file?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

There are cases where `git`'s automatic merging (patching) of text files produces bad outcome, due to logically conflicting changes, and I like to have those reported as a conflict instead of getting a silent merge.

#### Example

If two people fix the same bug by adding a missing line, but they add the same line in different places, `git pull` will likely add the same line *twice* to the file, which could cause trouble.

Instead, I want this reported as a conflict so that it has to be merged "by hand" later, e.g. by a person looking at it.

(Yes, the same issue could also happen with two separate files, if they somehow need to be in sync, but in my case that's not an issue; so let's focus only on single files in this question. I also know about the `--ff-only` option – and that would be what I'd use if I needed to prevent mixing of separate file changes from both sides).

---

I like to make sure this doesn't happen, i.e. I like to use an option for `git merge` or `git rebase` that won't try to merge / patch files that are changed on both the remote and the local side, and instead then stop the merge / rebase and report a conflict.

How can I accomplish that?

I'm using this for an automated system, where I write the git commands into a shell script, hence I can issue any number of commands that would help me figuring this out. This also means that I do not want to have an interaction in this process inserted - instead, if a such conflict is detected, I want the script to cancel the merge so that I can alert the user, e.g. by sending an email.

If `git` doesn't offer a direct option for this, any answer that would offer a shell script detecting such dual-side changes after having issued `git fetch` would be appreciated as well.

One thought: If the files were binary, where git can't create a patch, it would always report a file conflict. Maybe I can tell git somehow (but temporarily, i.e. only when I issue my scripted commands) to treat any file as a binary file?

Comment: Write a custom merge driver?

Comment: That'd too much effort for me. I hope to find a simple solution, not more work :)

Comment: It's not the task of Git to prevent people from working on the same bug. This is solved by other systems like Bugzilla, TFS or Gitlab, where issues are assigned to someone before they works on it. It's more efficient to fix this sort of problem in an earlier stage than at the time when it comes to a merge.

Comment: Add a line to .gitattributes to specify that the file is binary, then it won't be merged, but then you will need to remove that line again if you actually want git to merge it.

Comment: Also, for merging, there's the check-in dance. Even with no merge conflicts, developers should a) compile to see if the result is compilable b) run the (unit) tests in order to ensure that the merge was successful c) check if the fix they made is still present after the merge. If the duplicate line causes problems, it should be detected in one of these 3 steps.

Comment: Please refrain from trying to teach me on how to use git. I use the described procedure for an automated system, where these things happen for other reasons, so it's pointless to question that. Lasse's answer is the only constructive reply so far.